# Importing CSV to Database in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

In the following code i try to import from CSV to Database in WordPress.
The data is inserted but I get this error

```
WordPress database error: []
INSERT INTO wp_trav_accommodation_vacancies (date_from, date_to, accommodation_id, room_type_id, rooms, price_per_room, price_per_person) VALUES ('2017-08-30', '2017-09-10', '1', '1', '3', '600.00', '0.00')
```

This is the code I run:

```
global $wpdb;
    if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
    {
        $file = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $handle = fopen($file, "r");
        $c = 0;
        while(($filesop = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== false) {
            $date_from = $filesop[0];
            $date_to = $filesop[1];
            $accommodation_id = $filesop[2];
            $room_type_id = $filesop[3];
            $rooms = $filesop[4];
            $price_per_room = $filesop[5];
            $price_per_person = $filesop[6];



            $sql = "INSERT INTO wp_trav_accommodation_vacancies (date_from, date_to, accommodation_id, room_type_id, rooms, price_per_room, price_per_person) VALUES ('$date_from', '$date_to', '$accommodation_id', '$room_type_id', '$rooms', '$price_per_room', '$price_per_person')";

            if ($wpdb->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "You database has imported successfully";
            } else {
                echo $wpdb->print_error();
                my_print_error();
            }
        }

    }
```

Can anyone tell what is wrong?

Comment: are any of those fields required and are empty in your file. You may also have some data-type mismatches. For example trying to put a string into a date field or an integer into a string field, any number of issues. Can you post a few lines from csv file so we can see what may be going on. Can you also post your table definition for `wp_trav_accommodation_vacancies `. Another option could be to try to import the file directly in PhpMyAdmin

Comment: that might be the case... here is the link for my table structure: https://ibb.co/m0iswk

Comment: yes, I can see the post on my table... but I still get the error after insert.

Comment: another issue, you may not have permissions to update that table as the user that that connection is using. Can you post a few rows of what your csv would look like. are you sure that the file is actually uploading (you are not getting errors). Does your `$handle` exist?

Comment: if ($wpdb->query($sql) === TRUE)          (changed === to ==) and error message is gone success message is shown... seems its working good for the moment...